# Ear encoding inside the archive

Tags: java, encoding, ear, dos2unix

These days, I drove crazy to deploy an ear on unix enviroment using Weblogic.
At the end I realized by using (cat -v file.properties) that such file was full of ^M at the end of the line.
This happened because I edited the properties file on Windows and I transfered to the production eviromnment by FileZilla.
By the usage of dos2unix command, I addressed the problem and the encoding of the file right now is correct.
**Because the properties file it's not the only one I edit, but I open the ear archive and customize the config.xml too, and then close the ear again and transfer it to linux, do you think that the encoding of that xml can be a problem even if it's embedded inside the ear ?**
Thanks

Comment: Because when I move a file edited on Win to linux, it has ^M as a carriage return, doesn't it seems to be a problem ?

Comment: It might be.  _WAS_ it actually a problem?

Comment: Yes it was, I had a problem on the file properties, now I'm trying to rebuild the app with the properties file encoded for unix (when I do cat -v nameFile) there are no more ^M. I'm going to find out if it was the problem. But I still can't understand why you think it should be a no-problem.

Comment: I did not think it should not be a problem.  I asked if it was.

Comment: uhh ... okkey, forgive me for the misunderstandig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the carriage return characters automatically with ants  [fixcrlf](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fixcrlf.html).

If you use maven you could also run an ant task to prepare the files.